# Is it possible to use a Windows environment variable in a Chrome bookmark?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks, environment-variables

I use a software library whom I often refer to the documentation pages.
Those are html pages, therefore I created several bookmarks to quickly access to them.
However, when the library version changes, my bookmarks become deprecated.
I have a Windows environment variable that holds the library path. Is there a method to use it in order to create bookmarks I would not need to update every time the library version changes ?

Comment: What OS environment please!

Comment: Windows 7. I edited my questions to refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about environment variables, but I have a better solution. Why not create directory symbolic links instead?

For example, suppose you have a bookmark to `C:\Software Library\Version 1\Documentation\index.htm`, that broke because now you have `C:\Software Library\Version 2\Documentation\index.htm`.

Open an *elevated* Command Prompt, navigate to wherever you want to create the link (could even be on a different drive altogether), and issue the following command:

```
mklink /d Docs "C:\Software Library\Version 1\Documentation"
```

Now suppose you did this on D:\, you'd see `D:\Docs` (with a shortcut arrow overlay), which is actually a directory symbolic link to the original directory. Open `D:\Docs\index.htm` in your browser and add a bookmark to it (and any other sub-pages as well if you want).

*After* the version change, simply delete `D:\Docs` from Windows Explorer and issue the following command:

```
mklink /d Docs "C:\Software Library\Version 2\Documentation"
```

Now when you open the bookmark to `D:\Docs\index.htm`, it will automatically open Version 2 instead of Version 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I accepted your answer as there are no other suggestions. The thing that bothers me is that I might forget to update the symbolic link after a library version update, and I would not notice it since when using this method the version number is not displayed in the file path anymore in Chrome. However, it works fine.